# Set width with jQuery for Flot Chart

Tags: jquery, class, width, flot

I want to set a certain width in my jQuery for a Chart i've used on my page. I've set the width in my stylesheet using the class `.sparkline-width`. How can i call this class in my jQuery?

**HTML**

```
<div id="sparkline-1" class="sparkline sparkline-width"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#sparkline-1, #sparkline-3, #sparkline-5").sparkline([5,6,7,9,9,5,3,2,2,4,6,7], {
   type: 'line',
   spotColor: '#990000',
   minSpotColor: '#990000',
   maxSpotColor: '#990000',
   width: 
   height: '25px',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

```
$('.sparkline-width').width("Your width here");
```

Based on your comment, you can add new class to your element:

```
$("p").addClass("newClass");
```

then refer it in your css:

```
.newClass {
    /* Your styles here */
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want to refer to my css for the width so I can redraw the chart for different resolutions.